# What are returnType and argTypes in frida new NativeFunction?

Tags: javascript, python, frida

Example: `jstring __fastcall Java_com_yxcorp_gifshow_util_CPU_getClock(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jobject arg1, jbyteArray arg2, jint arg3){.....}`

```
var CPU_getClock = new NativeFunction(addr,returnType,argTypes)
```

returnType and argTypes What are they?
If the return value and the parameter of the function are other types, how can I write the corresponding returnType and argTypes?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look here: https://www.frida.re/docs/javascript-api/#nativefunction

returnType is the return type of the function you are wrapping at address `addr`. In your case, the Java function returns a jstring. As this is not native type, returnType value will be `'pointer'`.

argTypes is an array of types corresponding to the function parameters. In your case it's probably something like `['pointer', 'pointer', 'pointer', 'pointer', 'int']`. Basically, any non-native type will be a pointer.